# Using a format filter in Angular with results from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm getting documents from Mongodb into angular.  One of the variables is a date.  The return data for the date appears in this format:

"dateadded": "**Sun Apr 23 2017 18:09:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)**",

I thought I could just apply the angular filter in the HTML.

`{{ quote.dateadded | date:'yyyy'  }}`

for example to format the date.  No matter what date filter I try to apply, it always displays **`Sun Apr 23 2017 18:09:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)`**.

I can try other filters such as: `{{quote.dateadded | limitTo : 10 }}` and the it works to show the first 10 characters.  That implies to me it is seeing the return data as a string, not a js date object.  I've even tried a custom filter to know avail.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple in the data conversion but thought Angular handled it as JSON.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your date should be a timestamp value

Answer (score 0):

your date is a string. need to convert it to a date format in order to apply the `date` filter.

you can create an another custom filter to convert a string to date

```
.filter('stringDate',function(){
  return function(date){
    return new Date(date)
  }
})
```

then use the filters like this

```
{{quote.dateadded | stringDate | date : 'yyyy'}}
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.quote = {"dateadded": "Sun Apr 23 2017 18:09:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)"}

})
.filter('stringDate',function(){
  return function(date){
    return new Date(date)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 {{quote.dateadded | stringDate | date : 'yyyy'}}
</div>
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple with the conversion -- and it was! Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: @Jef sure no prob. make sure to check as right answer if this helped